# How would auto&& extend the life-time of the temporary object?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, temporary, lifetime

The code below illustrated my concern:

```
#include <iostream>


struct O
{
    ~O()
    {
        std::cout << "~O()\n";
    }
};

struct wrapper
{
    O const& val;

    ~wrapper()
    {
        std::cout << "~wrapper()\n";
    }
};

struct wrapperEx // with explicit ctor
{
    O const& val;

    explicit wrapperEx(O const& val)
      : val(val)
    {}

    ~wrapperEx()
    {
        std::cout << "~wrapperEx()\n";
    }
};

template<class T>
T&& f(T&& t)
{
    return std::forward<T>(t);
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << "case 1-----------\n";
    {
        auto&& a = wrapper{O()};
        std::cout << "end-scope\n";
    }
    std::cout << "case 2-----------\n";
    {
        auto a = wrapper{O()};
        std::cout << "end-scope\n";
    }
    std::cout << "case 3-----------\n";
    {
        auto&& a = wrapper{f(O())};
        std::cout << "end-scope\n";
    }
    std::cout << "case Ex-----------\n";
    {
        auto&& a = wrapperEx{O()};
        std::cout << "end-scope\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See it live [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d0f8f66f5f2b942).

It's said that `auto&&` will extend the life-time of the temporary object, but I can't find the standard words on this rule, at least not in N3690.

The most relevant may be section 12.2.5 about temporary object, but not exactly what I'm looking for.

So, would auto&& life-time extension rule apply to *all* the temporary objects involved in the expression, or only the final result?

More specific, is `a.val` guaranteed to be valid (non-dangling) before we reach the end-of-scope in case 1?

**Edit:**
I updated the example to show more cases (3 & Ex).

You'll see that only in case 1 the lifetime of O is extended.

Comment: with `auto&& val = wrapper{O()}.val`, no.

Comment: @Jamboree Do you ask specifically about `auto&&` or just lifetime extension? (After `auto&&` has been deduced, the default rules for reference binding apply. It's either a `wrapper const&` or `wrapper&&` or the binding will fail.)

Comment: @Jamboree IMO N3690 is currently a weird document to refer to. It includes some C++1y features, but [N3979](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) is the latest publicly available draft (besides the [github repository](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft)).

Comment: See http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1697 . EDG and GCC will not extend the lifetime. My understanding of the intent has been so far that it won't be extended (i considered the behavior of the implementations "correct" rather than the description in the Standard). We need to see how that issue will be resolved and whether the implementations officially will be kept wrong.

Comment: In particular, see the last bullet example in 12.2p5, which also initializes a reference member and where you can see that the lifetime is extended, according to the example's comment

Comment: @Dyp: what I mean is that `~O()` (I miss this one in my first reading) and `~wrapper()` are called, so the member of the temporary is really unsafe to use.

Comment: @Jarod42 Ah! I overlooked that `wrapper` stores a reference. I'm not sure if `~wrapper` will be called before the scope of `val` ends: Typically, the lifetime of a temporary object will be extended by binding a reference to it or to a subobject of that temporary. However, references are not objects, so I'm not sure if this applies here.

Comment: @DyP: thanks, I don't know lifetime expands with ref to subobject (I tested and references are not object), but it doesn't work with getter() through.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the same way that a reference to `const` does:

```
const auto& a = wrapper{O()};
```

or

```
const wrapper& a = wrapper{O()};
```

or also

```
wrapper&& a = wrapper{O()};
```

> > More specific, is `a.val` guaranteed to be valid (non-dangling) before we reach the end-of-scope in case 1?

Yes, it is.

There's (almost) nothing particularly important about `auto` here. It's just a *place holder* for the correct type (`wrapper`) which is deduced by the compiler. The main point is the fact that the temporary is bound to a reference.

For more details see [A Candidate For the “Most Important const”](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/) which I quote:

> > Normally, a temporary object lasts only until the end of the full expression in which it appears. However, C++ deliberately specifies that binding a temporary object to a reference to const on the stack lengthens the lifetime of the temporary to the lifetime of the reference itself

The article is about C++ 03 but the argument is still valid: a temporary can be bound to a reference to `const` (but not to a reference to non-`const`). In C++ 11, a temporary can **also** be bound to an rvalue reference. In both cases, the lifetime of the temporary is extended to the lifetime of the reference.

The relevant parts of the C++11 Standard are exactly those referred in the OP, that is, 12.2 p4 and p5:

> 4 - There are two contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a
>   different point than the end of the full expression. The first context
>   is [...]
>
> 5 - The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. [...]

(There are some exceptions in the bullet points following these lines.)

**Update**: (Following texasbruce's comment.)

The reason why the `O` in case 2 has a short lifespan is that we have `auto a = wrapper{O()};` (see, there's no `&` here) and then the temporary is **not** bound to a reference. The temporary is, actually, copied into `a` using the compiler generated copy-constructor. Therefore, the temporary doesn't have its lifetime expanded and dies at the end of the full expression in which it appears.

There's a danger in this particular example because `wrapper::val` is a reference. The compiler generated copy-constructor of `wrapper` will bind `a.val` to the same object that the temporary's `val` member is bound to. This object is also a temporary but of type `O`. Then, when this latter temporary dies we see `~O()` on the screen and `a.val` dangles!

Contrast case 2 with this:

```
std::cout << "case 3-----------\n";
{
    O o;
    auto a = wrapper{o};
    std::cout << "end-scope\n";
}
```

The output is (when compiled with gcc using option `-fno-elide-constructors`)

```
case 3-----------
~wrapper()
end-scope
~wrapper()
~O()
```

Now the temporary `wrapper` has its `val` member bound to `o`. Notice that `o` is not a temporary. As I said, `a` is a copy of the `wrapper` temporary and `a.val` also binds to
`o`. Before the scope ends the temporary `wrapper` dies and we see the first `~wrapper()` on the screen.

Then the scope ends and we get `end-scope`. Now, `a` and `o` must be destroyed in the reverse order of construction, hence we see `~wrapper()` when `a` dies and finally `~O()` when it's `o`'s time. This shows that `a.val` doesn't dangle.

(Final remark: I've used `-fno-elide-constructors` to prevent a optimization related to copy-construction that would complicate the discussion here but this is another [story](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19792864/1137388).)

Comment: If you look at the live demo, there is some strange thing.. the `O` in the second `wrapper` has a short lifespan

Comment: @texasbruce I've updated the post to give further explanations. I hope this helps to clarify the matter.

Comment: Just googled dangling reference to rvalue... interesting that the class is copied but the reference member is destroyed and dangling..

Comment: Remark: So the reference is not transitive, see my additional cases (3 & Ex) in which the lifetime is not extended. Case 1 with default initializer is really a special case.