# Can returning a braced enclosed initializer lead to a copy in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, return-value-optimization

Example:

```
struct s { int a; };

s func() { return {42}; }

int main() {
    s new_obj = func(); // line 6
    (void) new_obj;
    return 0;
}
```

This works. Now, what happens, if we assume that our compiler does no RVO?

1. `func` returns a struct of `s`, so `{42}` must be converted to `s`, is then returned and finally copied to `new_obj` in line 6.
2. `func` returns an initializer list, so a deep copy is impossible.

What does the language say? Can you give a proof?

Note: I know that this does not seem useful in this example, but for returning very large, constant sized `std::array`s, I do not want to rely on RVO.

Comment: “this might be good to know” – except that your compiler **does** in fact perform RVO.

Comment: @KonradRudolph What if for some reasons, RVO can not be used in one example. And even if - I thought that the C++ language does not guarantee RVO.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Shouldn't it move object, instead of applying (or possibly skipping) RVO?

Comment: @BЈовић: It is moved *semantically*, but in reality RVO could come and optimize it away! Note that RVO is a compiler feature, while move is a language feature... and the language allows the compilers to perform RVO wherever possible.

Comment: if it is possible it will RVO, if not it will move the object, if it's not possible it will copy it, in this order

Comment: @Drax No. An implementation is not requiered to do copy elision (RVO). And what do you mean by "it will move the object, if it's not possible ..."? If the move constructor is private or deleted, the program is ill-formed.

Comment: @BЈовић It should move only if it cannot apply RVO (like Nawaz said, the semantic action is a move but it may be elided). Omitting the move would obviously be better.

Comment: @Nawaz "and the language allows the compilers to perform RVO wherever possible." No! Every optimization is only allowed under the "as-if rule". RVO in form of what the spec calles "copy elision" is an exception to this rule.

Comment: @MWid: As if "wherever possible" is anti "as-if rule"!

Comment: @MWid Yes RVO is not required that's why i said "if it is possible". And if the move constructor is not implemented (not explicitly deleted nor private), it will call the copy constructor :)

Comment: Relevant post: [construction helper make_XYZ allowing RVO and type deduction even if XZY has noncopy constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19427196/construction-helper-make-xyz-allowing-rvo-and-type-deduction-even-if-xzy-has-non)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    foo(int) {}
    foo(const foo&) { std::cout << "copy\n"; }
    foo(foo&&)      { std::cout << "move\n"; }
};

foo f() {
    //return 42;
    return { 42 };
}

int main() {
    foo obj = f();
    (void) obj;
}
```

When compiled with gcc 4.8.1 with `-fno-elide-constructors` to prevent RVO the output is

```
move
```

If in `f` the return statement without curly braces is used then, then the output is

```
move
move
```

With no RVO, what happens is the following. `f` must create a temporary object of type `foo`, let's call it `ret`, to be returned.

If `return { 42 };` is used, then `ret` is *direct* initialized from the value `42`. So no copy/move constructor was called so far.

If `return 42;` is used, then another temporary, let's call it `tmp` is direct initialized from `42` and `tmp` is moved to create `ret`. Hence, one move constructor was called so far. (Notice that `tmp` is an rvalue and `foo` has a move constructor. If there was no move constructor, then the copy constructor would be called.)

Now `ret` is an rvalue and is used to initialize `obj`. Hence the move constuctor is called to move from `ret` to `obj`. (Again, in some circumstances, the copy constructor could be called instead.) Hence either one (for `return { 42 };`) or two (for `return 42;`) moves happen.

As I said in my comment to the OP's question, this post is very relevant:
[construction helper make_XYZ allowing RVO and type deduction even if XZY has noncopy constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19427196/construction-helper-make-xyz-allowing-rvo-and-type-deduction-even-if-xzy-has-non). Especially the excelent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19428052/1137388) by 
[R. Martinho Fernandes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46642/r-martinho-fernandes).

Comment: In case of braced-init-lists, `ret` is _copy-list-initialized_! If the converting constructor from `int` to `foo` is declared `explicit`, you get an error. Similarly in the case `return 42;`. It's always _copy-initialization_.

Comment: @MWid You're right. In addition, if a narrowing conversion is required during *list-initialization* (e.g. `return { 42.0 };`) then the code is ill-formed. I just wanted to focus on the main point of the OP's question (if/when copies/moves are made) and left these other questions aside.

Comment: Also see [this self-answered question by Johannes Schaub](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7935639/420683)