# Why does implementation of make_tuple not return via brace initialisation?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdtuple, c++17, list-initialization

To understand the question please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19428052/2712726) first.

I checked different historic `make_tuple` implementations (including clang versions of 2012). Before C++17 I would have expected them to `return {list of values ... }` but they all construct the tuple before returning it. They are all along the lines of the very simplified current cppreference example:

```
template <class... Types>
auto make_tuple(Types&&... args)
{
    return std::tuple<special_decay_t<Types>...>(std::forward<Types>(args)...);
}
```

Its not wrong but the point of returning brace initialization is to construct the returned object directly. Before C++17 there was no *guaranteed copy elision* which removes the temporaries even conceptually. But even with C++17 I would not necessarily expect the curly braces to disappear in this example.

Why no curly braces here in any of the C++11/14 implementations? In other words, why not

```
 template <class... Types>
    std::tuple<special_decay_t<Types>...> make_tuple(Types&&... args)
    {
        return {std::forward<Types>(args)...};
    }
```

Comment: You can't do that with return type `auto`.

Comment: @aschepler, yes, I know, but why is that a problem?

Comment: A braced-init-list has no type, so the return type cannot be deduced

Comment: @Praetorian, yes, I know, the return type cannot be auto, why must it be auto?

Comment: Because a braced initializer list alone is not assumed to be an initializer for a `std::tuple`. Could you make a rule that says that a braced initialization list for an `auto` results in a `std::tuple`? You could, but there is no such rule in C++.

Comment: Oh, you're asking why `auto` isn't replaced with `std::tuple<special_decay_t<Types>...>` and then a braced-init-list used in the return statement. You should edit the question to clarify that.

Comment: @Praetorian, I just did, but this is why I started of with please read . . . which should have made it clear.

Comment: @Praetorian, "I did, and it wasn't". I just do not understand that comment.

Comment: I read the question you linked to, and it still wasn't clear to me what you were asking

Comment: I think your writing isn't emphasizing the *combinations* enough since it doesn't establish this idea to your readers in early paragraphs. The second paragraph should've established the mention of the combination of "`auto` and `return tuple...`" and the combination of "`tuple` and `return {...}`", and subsequent paragraphs could refer to the combinations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The advantage you're talking about simply doesn't apply in this case. Yes, you can construct a non-movable type this way:

```
struct Nonmovable {
    Nonmovable(int );
    Nonmovable(Nonmovable&& ) = delete;
};

Nonmovable foo() { return {42}; } // ok
```

But in the context of `make_tuple`, all the elements *have* to be movable or copyable anyway, because you're going to be moving or copying them into the actual `tuple` that you're constructing:

```
std::tuple<Nonmovable> make_tuple(Nonmovable&& m) {
    return {std::move(m)}; // still an error
}
```

So there's not really an advantage to to:

```
template <class... Types>
std::tuple<special_decay_t<Types>...> make_tuple(Types&&... args)
{
    return {std::forward<Types>(args)...};
}
```

over

```
template <class... Types>
auto make_tuple(Types&&... args)
{
    return std::tuple<special_decay_t<Types>...>(std::forward<Types>(args)...);
}
```

in that sense.

Yes, by the language of the standard, one of these implies constructing directly into the return object and the other involves a temporary. But in practice, every compiler will optimize this away. The one case where it couldn't we already know doesn't apply - our `tuple` must be movable.

There is at least one weird downside to using `{...}` here, which is that on the off-chance a type has an `explicit` move or copy constructor, returning a *braced-init-list* doesn't work.

---

More importantly, as T.C. points out, until [Improving `pair` and `tuple`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4387.html) was adopted, the constructor for [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple) was **always** `explicit`.

```
// in C++11
explicit tuple( const Types&... args );

// in C++14
explicit constexpr tuple( const Types&... args );

// in C++17, onwards
/*EXPLICIT*/ constexpr tuple( const Types&... args );
```

Which made an implementation returning a *braced-init-list* impossible. So every library would have already had a `make_tuple()` implementation before C++17, which could not have used a *braced-init-list*, and there's no benefit to changing it - so we are where we are today.

Comment: Don't forget that that constructor is fully explicit until the "improve pair and tuple" paper.

Comment: @T.C. I did forget!