# Why the standard preferred round brackets initialization for `make_<something>`?

Tags: c++, initialization, stdtuple, list-initialization

The `std::make_` functions in the standard, such as:

- `std::make_unique` and `std::make_shared`
- `std::make_tuple`
- `std::make_from_tuple`

all use internally *round brackets initialization* rather than *curly brackets*.

For example, [`make_from_tuple` as presented by the standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/tuple.apply#2) is choosing to return `T(params...)` rather than `T{params...}`.

The result is that the following are illegal:

```
auto vec = std::make_from_tuple<std::vector<int>>(std::make_tuple());
auto arr = std::make_from_tuple<std::array<int, 2>>(std::make_tuple(9, 8));
```

---

<sub><sup>^</sup> the creation of `std::array` from a `tuple`, as above, is [illegal also with C++20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62041402/c20-initializing-aggregates-from-a-parenthesized-list-of-values-not-supportin), as [p0960 - allowing initialization of aggregates from a parenthesized list of values](https://wg21.link/p0960) becoming [part of the C++20 spec](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.6.2.2) doesn't allow such initialization for `std::array`, as its inner type is `T[size]` which cannot be initialized from a list of values (the parentheses are already being stripped by `std::array` initialization).</sub>

---

In cases where it does work, the selection of brackets initialization vs. curly brackets is meaningful:

```
auto vec2 = std::make_from_tuple<std::vector<int>>(std::make_tuple(2, 3));
// a vector with the values: {3, 3} surprise? :-)
```

(Above are of course *toy examples*. The supplied tuple may be provided externally).

With a *`curly_make_from_tuple`* like:

```
template<typename T, typename tuple_t>
constexpr auto curly_make_from_tuple(tuple_t&& tuple) {
    constexpr auto get_T = [](auto&& ... x){ return T{std::forward<decltype(x)>(x) ... }; };
    return std::apply(get_T, std::forward<tuple_t>(tuple));
}
```

all cases above would work, in a way that one may argue is more natural:

```
auto arr = curly_make_from_tuple<std::array<int, 2>>(std::make_tuple(9, 8)); // {9, 8}
auto vec = curly_make_from_tuple<std::vector<int>>(std::make_tuple());       // {}
auto vec2 = curly_make_from_tuple<std::vector<int>>(std::make_tuple(2, 3));  // {2, 3}
```

The question is: **why the standard chose *round brackets initialization* over *curly brackets*?**

---

**Related links:**

Similar question, from efficiency point of view: [Why does implementation of make_tuple not return via brace initialisation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48533080/why-does-implementation-of-make-tuple-not-return-via-brace-initialisation)

A nice [discussion and suggestions for adding curly brackets initialization option for the `make_` utilities](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-proposals/Wnl9w53uAiY/LMrphQibAgAJ).

The original paper proposing `make_from_tuple`, [P0209r2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0209r2.pdf), seem not to discuss the two alternatives `T(params...)` and `T{params...}`, maybe because all similar `make_` utility methods had already been using round brackets initialization.

Comment: Function call always uses round brackets. That's the language syntax. The curly brackets are for initializer lists.

Comment: Are you askig why they use `T(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x) ... )` instead of `T{std::forward<decltype(x)>(x) ... }`?

Comment: @NathanOliver yes, ignoring fancy options to support both (as discussed in the 2nd link provided at the end) if one should be supported, why the round brackets?

Comment: It's not an initialization, it's a function call `std::make_unique`, `std::make_shared`, `std::make_tuple`, etc. don't initialize things, they return the objects and the advantages of them are thread-safety, simplicity, etc.

Comment: @asmmo the question is on the ***internal*** implementation of these functions.

Comment: Another related question, with several interesting answers, can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55141594/make-unique-with-brace-initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it was not possible to initialize structure using braced-init-list in C++98.

So for consistency new standandard library features have used the same initialization form as the one used in the STL.

More over, it has never been changed to list-initialization for compatibility reason: list-initialization has not necessarily the same meaning as the equivalent parenthesized initialization form.

Comment: Which library function prior to C++11 was creating an object like that? Probably none, since it relies on variadic template. So if all such functions just appeared in C++11 or after, it could have used brace-initialization. Sure one has to be selected if not using a fancy approach to support both, but did the committee considered both? Was it an _intentioned decision_?

Comment: @AmirKirsh For exemple the STL allocator, for copy construction.