# C++20 initializing aggregates from a parenthesized list of values, not supporting inner array

Tags: c++, c++20, aggregate-initialization

C++20 adopted [p0960](https://wg21.link/p0960) - allowing initialization of aggregates from a parenthesized list of values.

The exact wording ([**[dcl.init]** 17.6.2.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.6.2.2)) says:

> [...] if no constructor is viable, the destination type is an aggregate
>   class, and the initializer is a parenthesized expression-list, the
>   object is initialized as follows.
>
> Let  e<sub>1</sub> , …,  e<sub>n</sub> be the elements
>   of the aggregate ([dcl.init.aggr]).
>
> Let  x<sub>1</sub>, …, x<sub>k</sub> be the elements of the expression-list.
>
> If k is greater than n, the program is ill-formed.
>
> The element e<sub>i</sub> is copy-initialized with x<sub>i</sub> for 1
>   ≤ i ≤ k . The remaining elements are initialized with their default
>   member initializers [...]

This doesn't allow initialization of inner array with parenthesized list of values:

```
struct Foo {
    int i, j;
};

struct Moo {
    int arr[2];
};

int main() {
    // before C++20:
    Foo foo1{1, 2};
    // with C++20:
    Foo foo2(1, 2); // p0960! we are good

    // before C++20:
    Moo moo1{1, 2};
    // C++20 - oops p0960 doesn't help here:
    Moo moo2(1, 2); // error: too many initializers

    // before C++20:
    std::array<int, 2> arr1{1, 2};   // OK
    std::array<int, 2> arr2({1, 2}); // OK
    std::array<int, 2> arr3{{1, 2}}; // OK
    // C++20 - oops p0960 doesn't help here:
    std::array<int, 2> arr4(1, 2); // error: too many initializers
}
```

The fact that `std::array` cannot be initialized with rounded brackets prevents it from participating in a generic code that creates an object of unknown type `T` from a list of values (e.g. an algorithm that uses `make_shared`, `make_unique`, `make_from_tuple` etc.).

---

### Why *p0960* didn't take a more simple approach making ***()-initialization*** more like ***{}***?

For example, something like:

> if no constructor is viable, the destination type is an aggregate
>   class, and the initializer is a parenthesized expression-list, the
>   object would be initialized as if the values were sent with brace-initialization.

Comment: Try to use  Moo moo2( { 1, 2 } ) or ( I have not checked ); Moo moo2( ( 1, 2 ) )

Comment: The first would work, but also before C++20. The second would not: `Moo moo3((1, 2)); // too many initializers` -- p0960 doesn't help here. The problem is that `std::array` still requires special care.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: `Moo moo2( ( 1, 2 ) )` would use comma operator there.

Comment: @AmirKirsh I noticed that this question is still listed as unanswered. Didn't I answer your question?

Comment: @TedLyngmo you have a very contributing answer, got my vote up, but l'm still missing the cons against trying to support std::array initialization via this change. Is there a way maybe to keep the mental model and still allow std::array initialization with some modifications to p0960?

Comment: @AmirKirsh Ok, thanks. `std::array` isn't special and follows the same rules as other classes. Your `Moo` and a `std::array<int, 2>` are very similar so you can initialize a `std::array<int ,2>` in the same way you initialize a `Moo`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes, I understand that, what I'm trying to get - and thus keeping the question open - is whether not supporting std::array initialization via () was an oversight of p0960, or was it an intentional sacrifice. It seems to me as a hole in p0960 that may require in the future another patch.

Comment: @AmirKirsh The change between r1 and r2 makes it look intentional i.m.o.. In r1 I think you would have gotten the initialization as you'd like it. It's the r2 addition "_... but as distinct as necessary to conform with the existing mental models of braced lists and parenthesized lists._" that changes that. Personally, I'm not a big fan of brace elision anyway so I'm fine with it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

p0960 changed between r1 and r2:

> r2: This revision changes the mental model from the original “literal rewrite to a braced list” to “*as if a synthesized, explicit constructor with appropriate mem-initializers was called*” <sup>**1**</sup>. This has the effect of allowing narrowing conversions in the parenthesized list, even when narrowing conversions would be forbidden in the corresponding braced list syntax. It also clarifies the non-extension of temporary lifetimes of temporaries bound to references, the absence of brace elision, and the absence of a well-defined order of evaluation of the arguments.

The reason why this change was made can be found in the changed design principles for p0960:

> r1: Parenthesized initialization and braced-initialization should be as similar as possible.
>
> r2:
> Parenthesized initialization and braced-initialization should be as similar as possible, but as distinct as necessary **to conform with the existing mental models** of braced lists and parenthesized lists.
> (*emphasis mine*)

"*Why p0960 didn't take a more simple approach making ()-initialization more like {}?*":

When the decision to go for conformance with the existing mental models <sup>**1**</sup> had been taken, not allowing brace elision seems like the *only* approach.