# Is -fno-elide-constructors contained in -O0 or any other optimization level?

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, c++11

Is -fno-elide-constructors contained in -O0 or any other -O[other level]?

In my view, -fno-elide-constructors is an optimization flag, and the -O is the optimization level. Hence, some -O level may include the flag -fno-elide-constructors.
Am I right?

In other words, is there any relationship between -fno-elide-constructors and -O..?

Comment: I believe it may be added through an optimization setting, I'm not sure of which one however.

Answer (score 2):

> In other words, is there relationships between -fno-elide-constructors
>   and -O..?

Yes there is a relationship, although a quite simple one: gcc will most likely elide constructors already at the `-O0` level unless you explicitly disable it. See the example code at the bottom for proof.

It is tricky though, the compiler can do really nasty things, see [RVO force compilation error on failure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19262009/341970). The bottom line is: You always need to check the generated assembly to see what is really happening under the hood.

Please keep in mind ([from Working Draft, Standard for Programming
Language C++, N3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) which is the closest approximation of C++14 that I could find):

> 12.8/31 When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit the copy/move construction of a class object, even if the constructor selected for the copy/move operation and/or the destructor for the object have side effects. [...]

---

The code substantiating my statement:

```
#include <cstdio>
constexpr int size = 1024;

struct A { int array[size] = { 0 }; };

int main() {
  A a = A();
  std::printf("%d\n", a.array[size-1]);
}
```

---

With `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -O0 -S elide.cpp`, in the generated assembly code there is only a single

```
    call    A::A()
```

However, with `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -O0 -fno-elide-constructors -S elide.cpp` I get:

```
    call    A::A()
    [...]
    call    A::A(A&&)
```

Even if you disable optimizations with `-O0`, you still have to disable elision additionally if you need it to be disabled for some reason.

Comment: About the: `Because some compilers do not perform copy elision in every situation where it is allowed, programs that rely on the side-effects of copy/move constructors and destructors are not portable.` This is not exact. That behavior is specifically described in the standard (C++14 12.8/31 and /32, or even C++98 12.8/15), so it is "portable". It's just that some compilers will do more copies than others. A bit like "long" can be 32-bit in some platforms, and 64-bit in others. My guess is that if you need to disable RVO to make sure you'll have some behavior, you are doing something fishy..

Comment: @paercebal Thanks, fixed! I guess whoever wrote "portable" meant that if you switch to another compiler then strange things can happen... :( Yes, I totally agree, it is fishy if someone depends on this behavior. Anyway, updated my answer, thanks!