# Disable elide constructors for one function under clang

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, optimization, clang

Trying to disable elide constructors for one function, the following function gives me the expected output under GCC, but not under clang. Under GCC, the output includes `copy cstr called` as expected, but not under clang, which gives the `warning: unknown attribute 'optimize' ignored [-Wattributes]` What could be happening? Should I be using anther keyword in place of 'optimize'?

```
#include <iostream>

class xyz {
 public:
  xyz() { std::cout << "cstr called\n"; }
  xyz(const xyz& A) { std::cout << "copy cstr called\n"; }
  xyz f() __attribute__((optimize("no-elide-constructors"))) {
    std::cout << "f called\n";
    xyz x;

    return x;
  }
};

int main() {
  xyz a;
  xyz b = a.f();
}
```

Comment: `__attribute__` are an extension in the GCC and Clang compilers. They do not share the same extensions, and therefore may have different `__attribute__` types and options.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, but AFAIK, -fno-elide-constructors works on both Clang and GCC, hence I guess both should respect this attribute.

Comment: @RadialApps Just because a two compilers support the same command line switch is the same, doesn't mean they support the same attributes.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude don't answer in comments ;)

Comment: @Caleth Didn't mean for it to be an answer. :)

Comment: AFAIK impossible for clang, there is only an optnone attribute (check the proposal http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/RFC-add-Function-Attribute-to-disable-optimization-td4032641.html). A per-function disable-specific-attribute-functionality is not supported.

Comment: @overseas, I tried optnone, but it doesn't seem to disable elide constructors either. Possibly because of the reasons [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070513/is-fno-elide-constructors-contained-in-o0-or-any-other-optimization-level?rq=1)