# std::move on the return value is causing extra temporary object creation

Tags: c++11, move-semantics

Why calling get_data2() results in additional c-tor call (g++ 4.7.1 -std=c++11 -O3)?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct data {
    data(data&&){std::cout << "cted(&&): " << (void*) this << std::endl; }
    data(data const&){std::cout << "cted(c&): " << (void*) this << std::endl; }
    data(){std::cout << "cted(): " << (void*) this << std::endl; }
    ~data(){std::cout << "dted(): " << (void*) this << std::endl; }
};

data create_data() { return data(); }

// with this one the c-tor is called twice
data get_data2() { return std::move(create_data()); }

// with this one the c-tor is called once
data get_data1() { return create_data(); }
int main() { data var = get_data1(); return 0; }
```

Output with get_data2():

```
cted(): 0x7ffffb2cd3df
cted(&&): 0x7ffffb2cd40f
dted(): 0x7ffffb2cd3df
dted(): 0x7ffffb2cd40f
```

Output with get_data1():

```
cted(): 0x7ffffd7f230f
dted(): 0x7ffffd7f230f
```

Comment: `std::move` there disables RVO. Why are you using it in the first place? `create_data` yields an rvalue anyways.

Comment: @Xeo - this is a test program aimed to demonstrate a particular way of std::move misuse I have seen in one program, this is why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the explicit `std::move` prohibits copy elision, see [Why does std::move prevent RVO?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19267408/341970) Another problem is that the explicit move is also unnecessary because in `data create_data() { return data(); }` you are already returning an rvalue.

As a side note: A very similar question came up a while ago and it turned out that the way you are using to track object creation is very unreliable, partly because the object is empty, see [RVO force compilation error on failure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19262009/341970).

Long story short: use only the `data create_data() { return data(); }` version.

Comment: The reason the subject source code fragment attracted my attention is precisely because I didn't see why std::move would be required when returning a temporary. A further investigation shown it is even harmful. The first link you gave is answering the question.